# using jQuery .each() method on single-element id-selector

Tags: jquery

Explaining [jQuery dialogs](http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/18/loading-a-page-into-a-dialog/) in the Nemikor Blog, Scott González uses the .each() method on an id selector:

```
$('#page-help').each(function() {
  var dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .load($(this).attr('href'))
    .dialog( ... );
  $(this).click(function() { ... });
});
```

Since an id selector can only return a single element, what is the purpose of using the .each() method? (which is normally for iterating over matched elements).

Is it just that there is no simpler way to execute a function for the 'page-help' element which provides access to $(this)?

Comment: Thanks everyone, it seems that using a method intended for iterating is actually the clearest and simplest way of accessing a single object, in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It lets you mess with something without polluting the surrounding namespace. An alternative might be:

```
(function($this) {
  var dialog = $('<div></div>')
    .load($this.attr('href'))
    .dialog(...);
  $this.click(function() { ... });
})($('#page-help'));
```

I don't know which of the two is more disturbing. And I suppose I don't *really* know that that was the reason for doing it that way (that is, namespace tidiness).

Answer (score 1):

He's using a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) so `this` refers to the element and his variables are encapsulated in that callback function, though this would also work (but you'd have the variables left around):

```
var $this = $('#page-help'),
    dialog = $('<div></div>')
      .load($this.attr('href'))
      .dialog( ... );
$this.click(function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a style choice.  I actually like the selector way you show here because it attaches a scope to the primary participant in the logic in a (to me) self documenting way.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be done like this, but that wrapper gives you the fortunate use of $(this) instead of the following code:

```
var idPageHelp = $( $('#page-help')[0] );
var dialog = $('<div></div>')
  .load( idPageHelp.attr('href'))
  .dialog( ... );
idPageHelp.click(function() { ... });
```

Note I'm making an assumption that you want to focus on just the 0th element and I'm also focusing that you want to use idPageHelp as a jQuery object so I'm forcing it to be wrapped in a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just assign a variable?

```
var ph = $('#page-help')
var dialog = $('<div></div>')
ph.load($(this).attr('href'))
ph.dialog( ... );
$(ph).click(function() { ... });
});
```

Comment: Because now that variable is just there floating around, ready to be inadvertently picked up by some innocent closure later on.